# Cannot change MenuItem background

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, colors, background

Hello I have an issue.

I cannot change background of MenuItem in XAML. I set background using many ideas and it still doesn't work. Look at the picture please, I want the hole menu and all menu items to be blue. (only background of menu changed, but menuitem didn't change)

[image]

And here is the code:

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource menuStyle}">
                <MenuItem Header="Wygląd" Style="{StaticResource menuItemStyle}" >
                    <MenuItem Header="Motywy" Style="{StaticResource menuItemStyle}">
                        <MenuItem Header="Jasny" Style="{StaticResource menuItemStyle}"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="Ciemny" Style="{StaticResource menuItemStyle}"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="Domyślny" Style="{StaticResource menuItemStyle}"></MenuItem>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="PLik" Style="{StaticResource menuItemStyle}"></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="PLik" Style="{StaticResource menuItemStyle}"></MenuItem>
                    <Separator></Separator>
                    <MenuItem Header="PLik" Style="{StaticResource menuItemStyle}"></MenuItem>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="File" Style="{StaticResource menuItemStyle}"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="File" Style="{StaticResource menuItemStyle}"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="File" Style="{StaticResource menuItemStyle}"></MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </DockPanel>


<Application.Resources>
        
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="appBackgroundColour" Color="#FFD0E281"/>

        <Style TargetType="Menu" x:Key="menuStyle">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aqua"></Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="MenuItem" x:Key="menuItemStyle">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aqua"></Setter>
        </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

How to change the colour of the MenuItem background?

Comment: I get everything in Aqua if I run your XAML.
Do you have the resources 'menuStyle' and 'menuItemStyle' defined more than once (for example also in *Window.Resources* ) and the green ones have higher prio and hide the *Application.Resources* ?

Comment: Btw sometimes it helps to delete "obj" and "bin" folders if you get bizarre behaviours after having done a lot of layout...

Comment: I haven't any XAML reference in Window.Resources and I haven't defined 'menuStyle' and 'menuItemStyle' more than once.
I deleted "obj" and "bin" but it didn't help.

Comment: Okay I spotted that the whole menu background depends on Grid colour, because all my controls are inside grids.
  <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource appBackgroundColour}"/>
        </Style> .If i change Grid colour, the whole menu changes.

Comment: ok, glad you found it

Comment: Yes, I changed code a bit and it works. Thanks for help.